# How to change ownership of a mounted disk, or what should I do?

Tags: permissions, mount, disk

My Ubuntu install (20.04 LTS / focal) is going great. But now, I've got 3 SCSI hdd on to which I need to dump data. I mount them under **$HOME/Data/**  where they are all erased / formatted (**mkfs.ext4**) with 1 large partition on each disk / ready to go. But, they are all owned by **root**, so I can't write to them.

I can't get any variations of *sudo chown* or *sudo chmod* to allow me to get write access to these mounted drives. This pc is only for me, and would be ok mounting them elsewhere other than $HOME. Is the only way, to do the **fstab** edits (I don't know those yet), reboot, and that is how to get write access? That seems strange. And, so there's no way a user other than root can write to mounted drives. I'm confused. I can reformat the drives, if that is part of the fix. They are Linux(ext4).

I've got another SCSI disk to add as well. While I think I've got the basics of disk management down, the above problem is a non-starter for my using Linux to manage my data.

Comment: You cannot mount all three at same place. Use 3 different mount points. If ext4 chown & chmod work. I mount in /mnt/data & link partitions into /home. But if only one partition, probably easier just to directly mount into /home. Details including chown & chmod: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk